# Как менять ширину и высоту окна (stage) пропорционально в JavaFX ?

Tags: javafx

Нужно что бы Scene всегда была квадратной. Значит нужно следить и за размерами Stage. То есть, если пользователь меняет ширину окна(stage), автоматически должна меняться высота окна(stage). Есть ли метод, который это делает? ( например *stage.setProportional(true)* )

Разумно ли влиять на размеры Scene с помощью изменения Stage ? (думаю что Scene автоматически подстраивается под размеры Stage, при этом размерами Scene нельзя управлять напрямую после ее создания)

Не важно что бы Scene была именно квадратной. Главное сохранить пропорции окна, когда пользователь меняет его размер. Как это сделать?

Comment: Так важно или неважно, чтобы квадрат?

Comment: думаю надо поставить слушателя на изменение размера и менять вторую составляющую в нем. Не понятно только как с углами быть, когда сразу две стороны двигаются

Comment: @Эникейщик , как сделать scene квадратной я понимаю, поэтому говорю что это не главное. То есть в JavaFX нет такой функции, которая сохраняет пропорциональность окна? Вопрос "что делать с углами?" меня так же интересует.